# Recursive types based on object keys

Tags: node.js, typescript

Im trying to create a function that takes the outer most keys in an object type as an argument and returns a new function that then takes the next outer most keys of the object from the given key recursively until no more keys are available.

**Example**

```js
const values = {
  a: {
    aa: {
      aaa: 'hello aaa',
    }
  },
  b: {
    bb: 'hello bb',
  }
} as const;

// should work
foo<typeof values>('a')('aa')('aaa');
foo<typeof values>('b')('bb');

// should fail
foo<typeof values>('c');
foo<typeof values>('a')('b');
```

I already made a function that does something like this but fails whenever there is more than one key at the same level :(

**My current code**

```js
const valuesA = {
  a: {
    aa: {
      aaa: 'hello aaa',
    }
  }
} as const;

const valuesB = {
  a: {
    aa: {
      aaa: 'hello aaa',
    }
  },
  b: {
    bb: {
      bbb: 'hello bbb',
    }
  }
} as const;


function foo<T>() {
  return function (key: keyof T) {
    type U = T[typeof key];
    return foo<U>();
  };
}

const booA = foo<typeof valuesA>();
const booB = foo<typeof valuesB>();

booA('a')('aa')('aaa'); // WORKS! :D
booB('a')('aa');        // FAILS! :(
```

`booB` give the following error message:

```js
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

Is there a way to make `B` work? - Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout this recursive conditional type:

```
type ValueOrFn<T> = <K extends keyof T>(key: K) =>
  T[K] extends object
    ? ValueOrFn<T[K]>
    : T[K]
```

This type takes `T` as a parameter and returns a function type that accepts a `keyof T`.

The return value of that function is either `T[K]` we found a primitive value, or recursively return `ValueOrFn<T[K]>` if we have an object and therefore expect further drill ins.

Let's try it:

```
declare const foo: ValueOrFn<typeof values>

const test1A = foo('a')('aa')('aaa') // 'hello aaa'
const test1B = foo('b')('bb') // 'hello bb'
```

---

One thing to note here is that this *can't* work:

```
foo<typeof values>('a');
```

This is because the invocation of `foo` requires two generic type parameters:

- `typeof values` The object to drill into.
- `'a'` the key to use to drill into the object.

You need both of those in order for the type system to do `T[K]` and drill into that object.

But here one is explicit (the `typeof values`) and one is inferred (the key `'a'`). And in typescript all generic function parameters must be either explicit or inferred.

---

But there are some work arounds:

So you could wrap it in a function, which separates this into two function calls.

```
declare const fooWrapped: <T>() => ValueOrFn<T>

const test2A = fooWrapped<typeof values>()('a')('aa')('aaa');
const test2B = fooWrapped<typeof values>()('b')('bb');
//                                      ^ Note extra parens
```

However, this is only a problem if you don't accept value that you can get the type from. And by doing so, it serves as a natural way to break of the type parameters anyway.

```
declare const fooObj: <T>(obj: T) => ValueOrFn<T>

const test3A = fooObj(values)('a')('aa')('aaa');
const test3B = fooObj(values)('b')('bb');
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAbgQwDYFcCmEYF4YG8CwAUDDAgFx5EkkLmXHU20UDkAFmkkiKbSwDRVqAXyHDBDAEYUCDEpOkx2nbjAUCxRYaUyhIUANxEiUAJ4AHNDABqydAHkATgDEwAHgAqAPmww3AaRg0AA8oNDAAE0wAazRTEAAzGG8ACljTCn8ASmwvIQ8AbX8AXSDQ8KiYEEkAKzRgKCESAH4bOzQnV08i4ry5GApCkuNCCPqkBEcrPWgYBJAQCltUDpd3M0tE+HaIPqIZ2DDoAEZfeZAUlgQWLMu+W6v7kYB6Z5Gx4AmpmAO5hYB1RwIcyWCIUTxeFI5LA+ZYONYQka-I5QABMAEEzgCgSC0BE3Bs0FtECtdlC7jc7tcHrRqUZCMiMGiAEJYkCA4GggkWIlJEnoMkPSSUljqLL0oivd7jSbTcCzc72Wrg1LVGqDaGw9qddzeJHyw5MgDMmJwitqKX5GBpIvuVLp+wNMBRRtZZoWSpqlp2QpFYolhElzxgEDYIBQSAicwQAEskERzhzcfjCcSdpCHsAbvTEziuam+enyVc-dmgA)

Comment: thanks Alex it works perfect :) nice description too - you are a wizard